# Reuse AWS External Application LoadBalancer with same DNS name on reinstall/delete service on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have 1-2 Kubernetes LoadBalancer services and I want to keep the LoadBalancer DNS name same on recreation or deletion of these services.

The changes to LoadBalancer kubernetes services lead to deletion of previous loadbalancer which also changes the DNS name of LoadBalancer.

How can reuse the Loadbalancer when the services are recreated? I checked AWS load balancer controller but didn't find the exact step to implement when services
are recreated.